JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory | cordova
Я пытаюсь запустить cordova run android, но получаю
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-23

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

Что я делаю не так? Я проверил, все в интернете говорят делать так. Я пробовал 17 и 23 версии.
Работаю на windows


А зайдите в Program Files\Java, да проверьте, правда ли каталог с jdk называется именно jdk-23. И нет ли где-то лишних пробелов в имени каталогов - у JAVA и у jdk каталога. Да, и, кстати, попробуйте обратные слеши, как положено в винде: JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-23"

Вообще никак. Проверил все буквы, слеши, пробелы. После каждого изменения перезагружал компьютер чтобы точно. Ничего не помогает

А в PATH добавили C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-23/bin?

Добавил, но все равно эта ошибка

Даже не знаю. Покажите, что говорит dir "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-23" на всякий случай.

Прикрепил к вопросу

Ну так вы так и пишите пути с обратными косыми чертами, а не с обычными, не все программы умеют преобразовывать пути.

Кому интересно и не только в теме есть разное включая исходный код и настройку эмулятора при работе с файлами. В общем прошедшим летом я рассказывал как начать работу с Java и начать писать под Android http://forum.old-dos.ru/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=2103

К счастью я смог найти решение! Это проблема из-за самой cordova. Используйте
cordova build android

А затем откройте в андроид студии проект из папки /platforms/android и спокойно запускайте
И с этим я мучился 3 дня 
